# Can I use 2 cameraUpdates with one animateCamera?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to zoom on a map

```
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mBounds, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels,
                        height, padding);
mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, duration, null);
```

And after that I want to scroll the map vertically

```
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate =
        CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0, amountToScroll);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, duration, null);
```

The thing is ... it is not working. If I call the scroll right after the zoom, only the scroll is taken into account. If I scroll the map once the zoom animation is finished I will have 2 animations.

I would like to do both operations with the same animation, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you call `animateCamera` multiple times, only the last one will finish its action.

The easy fix would be to use `moveCamera` instead of the first call to `animateCamera`, but that's not a nice solution from UX perspective.

The other way would be to do the math yourself and fill `mBounds` with the bounds you really want to show.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree, using moveCamera is not nice, I had already tried it. I don't understand what the other way is. I am already filling mBounds by myself (it's a LatLngBounds object). I only need to move the camera in order to zoom in on these bounds.

Comment: @user1990021 E.g. if your `mBounds` holds `[20,20; 30,30]` initially and after scrolling you show `[22,20; 32,30]`, you need your `mBounds` to hold the second value instead and skip `scrollBy` animation. That's math to calculate second value using first and zoom value.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use CancelableCallback. You should check the first action is complete and then call the second:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, size.x, height, 0), new CancelableCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    CameraUpdate cu_scroll = CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0, 500);
                    mMap.animateCamera(cu_scroll);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }
            });
```