# google map animateCamera- > cameraposition target not updating & moveCamera -> cameraposition target updating

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android.i know the difference between google map animateCamera and moveCamera . But I am not sure my doubt is valid or not.Actually in my application, in map centre am having one icon. if we move the map ,app will return the centre location of map.Example :Suppose if I change the centre of the map with some lat long by using move camera like this ,

```
       CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(0.0,0.0))     
                    .zoom(14)                   
                    .bearing(90)               
                    .build();                  
       map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

If I get the center of map now is,

```
  Log.e("Location",map.getCameraPosition().target);
```

Output is : 0.0,0.0

And same operation using animate camera,
                      CameraPosition cameraPosition = new

```
      CameraPosition animateCameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(2.0,4.0))     
                    .zoom(14)                   
                    .bearing(90)               
                    .build(); 
   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(animateCameraPosition));
```

Now the center of map now is,

```
  Log.e("Location",map.getCameraPosition().target);
```

Output is : 0.0,0.0

I don't know what I am doing wrong ? why animateCamera is not updating the center of the map?

[image: Screenshot of log]

Comment: it seems like you wanted to use different variable (animateCameraPosition) in your animate line?

Comment: @NikMarkin but am setting animateCameraPosition object to same map object right ?

Comment: You are using same cameraPosition in animateCamera and moveCamera

Comment: Use the 'GoogleMap.CancelableCallback()' on the animate and capture the location in 'onFinish' - it takes time for the animate to complete so you can't sample it right after invoking.

Comment: @Andy can you please post the sample code

Comment: I just searched on 'GoogleMap.CancelableCallback' in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661911/can-i-use-2-cameraupdates-with-one-animatecamera/26607167#26607167 .  Replace the 'onFinish' code with your location Log statement.

Comment: @Andy I ll check and let you know,,

Comment: @Andy . It s working thanks a lot